# Set H2 schema on connection

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, h2

I am configuring an h2 test database for our oracle production database. All tables are of the schema `xxx`. My datasource is defined as below:

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS xxx;SCHEMA=xxx");
    ds.setUser("xxx");
    ds.setPassword("xxx");
    return ds;
}
```

With `SCHEMA=xxx`, I get an error: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "xxx" not found; SQL statement: SET SCHEMA xxx [90079-186]`

Without `SCHEMA=xxx`, I get errors whenever Hibernate attempts to run a query with a join because it does not prepend the schema to the table name. It does this in production with our oracle database though.

Edit:
To provide some more insight, I am populating my db from creation scripts that are also used in production:

```
@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.setSeparator(";");
    populator.setCommentPrefix("--");
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db-schema.sql"));
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db-init-data.sql"));
    return populator;
}
```

Comment: Have you verify that the schema exist? Case sensitive maybe?

Comment: It exists because it is created with `INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS xxx`. Everything else works as expected besides queries that cause joins.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This connection string worked:       `ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS xxx\\;SET SCHEMA xxx");`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you should use `hibernate.hbl2ddl.auto=create` to create scheme on connection.

Here some info
[Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)

Comment: My DDL script has the proper schema and the table is created under that schema. The only issue is that joins are looking for a table called `ROLE_PERMISSION` not `xxx.ROLE_PERMISSION`